# Type of generated fold, iter and map not coherent with ppx_deriving documentation

Tags: ocaml, fold, ocamlfind

I am struggling to properly set up my OCaml environment to use ppx derivers map, fold and iter, as devined here: 
https://github.com/ocaml-ppx/ppx_deriving#plugins-iter-map-and-fold

My minimal example is here (I am using Base since this is a library I am using in my wider project):

```ml
open Base;;

type data = Row of float array | Dim of data array
[@@deriving iter, map, fold, show];;

let t = Row [|2.;2.|];;
pp_data Caml.Format.std_formatter t;;
map_data (fun x -> x +. 1.) t;;
pp_data Caml.Format.std_formatter t;;
```

The following code is compiled with
`ocamlfind ocamlc -package base -package ppx_deriving.iter -package ppx_deriving.map -package ppx_deriving.fold -package ppx_deriving.show -linkpkg -g test.ml && ./a.out`; I get a compilation error stating that `map_data` has type `data -> data`. But according to the documentation and my general knowledge, `map` gets a function and a mappable structure, which seems not to be the case here. Testing this in utop gives me the same error.

Is there anything I am missing?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These derivers work on *polymorphic* data structures and apply a user function to all values corresponding to the type variables of that structure. Since you don't have any type variables the generated `map_data` function is deficient, but quite natural, as an absence of the type variable implies a constant function.

In other words, the general structure of the `map_x` function for some polymorphic `type ('s1, ..., 'sN) x` with `N` type variables is

```
('s1 -> 't1) -> ... -> ('sN -> 'tN) -> ('s1,...,'sN) x -> ('t1,...,'tN) x
```

I.e., for each type variable it expects a function that maps values of that type to some other type so that the number of arguments to the map function is `N+1` In your case since you have zero type variables, there are no mapping functions so you have just `x -> x`.

If you will redefine your type  as

```
type 'a data = Row of 'a array | Dim of 'a data array
[@@deriving iter, map, fold, show]
```

You will get `map_data` with the expect type `('a -> 'b) -> 'a data -> 'b data`. The deriver will even understand that an array is a data structure and recurse into it, e.g.,

```
let input = Dim [|Row [|1;2;3|]; Row [|3;4;5|]|]
map_data (fun x -> x + 1) input;;
- : int data = Dim [|Row [|2; 3; 4|]; Row [|4; 5; 6|]|]
```

Of course, if you don't want a polymorphic type in your interface, you can always create a type alias, e.g.,

```
type t = float data
```

and expose map_data as

```
val map_data : (float -> float) -> t -> t
```